# What does this syntax "success |= MAX35101_Read_2WordValue(TOF_DIFF_AVG_REG, &TOF_DIFF_Results->TOF_DiffData);" mean? in C/C++ language?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, embedded, microcontroller

I am trying to decode the reference code to access the registers in MAX35101 IC.

The code has this syntax at various lines.

What does this mean?

```
bool MAX35101_Update_TOF_AVG_DIFFData(Flow_ResultsStruct* TOF_DIFF_Results)

{

    bool success = false;
        success |= MAX35101_Read_2WordValue(TOF_DIFF_AVG_REG, &TOF_DIFF_Results->TOF_DiffData);  
    return success;
}
```

Simply what does `Z |= X(a, &b->c);` mean?

Comment: [tag:C] does not have a boolean type. This is C++.

Comment: @Gerhard C has `_Bool`.

Comment: I mean there is either [tag:C] or [tag:c++] it can not be not be both. So tag the question with the correct tag and remove the tag that is not applicable.

Comment: @Gerhard ... and stdbool.h that defines `bool` as an alias of `_Bool`. But yest it should not be tagged C _and_ C++.

Comment: It is an over complicated way of saing simply `return MAX35101_Read_2WordValue(TOF_DIFF_AVG_REG, &TOF_DIFF_Results->TOF_DiffData);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Z |= X(a, &b->c);` could be rewritten as `Z = Z | X(a, &(b->c));`

We have a pointer to a struct `Flow_ResultsStruct* b`. To access a member of a struct via a pointer we use a `->`. So it is get the address of member `c` of struct `b` for which we have a pointer.

Pass `a` and the address to X.

Now logical or (`|`) the return value with `Z` which is false (`0`) so `Z` equals the return of the function.

Comment: Okay. Actually what does X(a, &(b->)) means? Particularly, &(b->c).